# How do I enable incremental compilation with Maven in Eclipse?

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, m2e

Using Maven and Eclipse and launching using a Maven Run Configuration with *jetty:run* (org.eclipse.jetty::artifactId::jetty-maven-plugin).

If I change the code beyond the method level, e.g. adding a new class, I get recompilation of all code, as follows.

(I timed this compilation and also a full compilation after cleaning--it really is recompiling everything.)

How do I enable incremental compilation?

```
[INFO] Changes detected - recompiling the module!
[INFO] Compiling 2204 source files to D:\dev\tradeos\target\tradeos-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT\WEB-INF\classes
```

*pom.xml* snippet

```
<plugin>
    <!--Override compiler and java version -->
    <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>${maven.compiler.plugin.version}</version>
    <configuration>
        <source>${maven.compiler.source}</source>
        <target>${maven.compiler.target}</target>
        <compilerId>jdt</compilerId>

    </configuration>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>

            <groupId>org.eclipse.tycho</groupId>
            <artifactId>tycho-compiler-jdt</artifactId>
            <version>${jdt.compiler.version}</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</plugin>
```

Comment: I wonder how you configured this; in my mavenized projects Eclipse does its own compiling if the code which is nice and incremental. The only task of m2e is to sync the pom settings to the Eclipse projects.

Comment: @gimby You are right, Eclipse does compile nicely as I develop code. But I am launching using a Maven Run Configuration with *jetty:run* (org.eclipse.jetty::artifactId>jetty-maven-plugin). That is when the lengthy Maven build process occurs.